# Generalizing in Mathematics

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I was reading the book "Fermat's Last Theorem" by Simon Singh when it hit me that this theorem is so contrived, andyet it lead to several important breakthroughs in mathematics and especially the theory of numbers. However, the fact that the breakthroughs only gradually emerged one after the other over a period of 300 years makes it unfeasible to do this with other problems: It is extremely hard to get mathematicians that motivated about a contrived statement. So my question is this:

Is the fact that the problem was so unbelievably difficult to solve a large contributing factor to how it lead to several important breakthroughs? (For example, would we be able to get as much new mathematics out of a random contrived olympiad problem as we did out of Fermat's Theorem, or is this unlikely due to the relative triviality of the olympiad problem?)

To put it another way, is there anything special about Fermat's Last Theorem as opposed to any other contrived statement someone might make? (This is harking back to Gauss' reply when asked why he didn't seriously attempt the problem: "I confess that Fermat’s Theorem as an isolated proposition has very little interest for me, because I could easily lay down a multitude of such propositions, which one could neither prove nor dispose of.")

Please feel free to discuss other related questions in your answer.

Comment: The idea is hard to break. It always want to destroy. Always the right authority who say, " today we'll solve the problem. Times mentioned the tower Farm - let's try to solve any equation. For example, this:  $aX^2+bXY+cY^2=jZ^2$ ?

Comment: See [Perfect Cuboid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectCuboid.html).

Comment: I have no doubt that a simple proof of FLT will one day be discovered. However, I'm very happy that it wasn't discovered earlier, since — as you say — so much wonderful machinery was discovered by all the great minds who tried to prove it (all but one, unsuccessfully) over the centuries.